# how to fetch all dates as array from database in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I have a holiday_list table with column names occasion and date. I show the list of holidays according to current year.

```
class HolidayListsController < ApplicationController
def index
    @holidays = HolidayList.by_year(Time.now.year)
end
end
```

query in model method like this:-

```
def self.by_year(year)
  where('extract(year from date) = ?', year)
end
```

from above code i get whole data as array in result

```
 <ActiveRecord::Relation [#<HolidayList id: 1, name: "independence day", date: "2015-08-15",created_at: "2015-06-04 07:19:02", 
    updated_at: "2015-06-04 07:19:02">, #<HolidayList id: 2, name: "Republic day",date: "2015-01-26", created_at: "2015-06-04 08:39:57",
    updated_at: "2015-06-04 08:39:57">
```

but I want all values of date column as an array.so that i can apply this array in my jQuery.

Comment: return `@holidays.collect(&:date)`

Comment: You can try this `@holidays = HolidayList.by_year(Time.now.year).collect{ |d| d.date }`

Comment: @usmanali **@holidays.collect(&:date)** give a single array for all dates  but i want single date as a single array

Comment: If I am getting you right, it should  `@holidays.collect{holiday| [holiday.date] |}` .

Answer (score 1):

```
def self.by_year(year)
  where('extract(year from date) = ?', year)
end
```

This will make query where `year` is `eq to`, then you have to take array fo dates, using `pluck` function, [how pluck works](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck)

```
def self.by_year(year)
  where('extract(year from date) = ?', year).pluck :date
end
```

Method `by_year` will return `array` of dates

Answer (score 0):

In `HolidayList` model class:

```
scope :from_year, ->(year) { time = Time.new(year); where(created_at: time.beginning_of_year..time.end_of_year) }
```

Then in controller:

```
def index
  @holidays = HolidayList.from_year(Time.now.year).pluck(:date) # you can now use this for another year as well, just pass the year at the place of Time.now.year. For example: '2015'
end
```